# Optimizing integrals

Tags: integration, derivatives, definite-integrals, optimization, chain-rule

I only just started doing integration and I came across a problem where I was asked to optimise the surface area of a tin can with ribbed sides. $r$ is the radius and $V$ is a constant volume of the tin can. The question is below:

$$A=2\pi r^2+\int_0^{\frac{3V}{2\pi r^2}}\sqrt{4\pi^2r^2+\frac{16\pi^4r^2}{9}\cos^2\left(\frac{20\pi}{3}x\right)}\text{d}x+\frac{V}{2r}$$

Find $$\frac{\text dA}{\text d r}$$

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! I have typed out your question - take a look at how I have done it, and learn for the future. Also, check out [this tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: I've read website on differentiating indefinite integrals, but I don't know how to differentiate a definite integral where the upper bound has 2 variables.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** You can try the [Leibniz´s rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) to compute the derivative of the term in the middle

$$\frac{d}{dr} \int_{u(r)}^{v(r)}f(r,x) \,  dx =f(r,v(r))\cdot \frac{dv}{dr}-f(r,u(r))\cdot \frac{du}{dr}+\int_{_{}^{u(r)}}^{v(r)} \frac{\partial f(r,x)}{\partial r} \, dx$$

with $u(r)=0, v(r)=\frac{3V}{2\pi \cdot  r^2}$